# MAC Sierra CodeBlocks : Cannot run executable

Tags: c, macos, codeblocks, executable

First of all I would like to specify that this is my first time around CodeBlocks or C language in general. English isn't my native language either, so please excuse me in advance.

I'm running a program on CodeBlocks (13.2) that was originally written for Windows and Linux. My Mac OS is 10.12.16 (Sierra) and I use gcc compiler. Everything is more or less fine, compilation seems to work. However I cannot run the executable, and encounter this message (screenshot) :

> Unable to open "file" for write

> *Segmentation fault: 11*.

I checked permissions : I, the administrator, can read and write everything in theory. Same type of error in Xcode (9.2). I also tried to run it from terminal, but same result. Is it a permission thing? Is it something else, and how can I fix it?

I appreciate any help. Thank you!

[Build log after rebuild](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYByW.png)
[Terminal console log, build target is "Release"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Njpbo.png)

Comment: this is (almost) sure to be a problem in your source code.  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it

Comment: please do not post links to your info.  Rather, copy/paste the info directly into your question